# Thor's age in Infinity War vs actual norse mythology Thor

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, avengers-infinity-war, thor-mythology

I always thought MCU's Thor was a fictional expansion to the actual norse God of Thunder. There are some quotes in the first Thor movie that supports this:

Heimdall says:

> In ages past, they looked to us as
>             gods, for indeed so many times we
>             saved them from calamity. We tried
>             to show them how their world was
>             but one of the Nine Realms of the
>             Cosmos, linked to all others by the
>             branches of Yggdrasil, the Worlds Tree. Nine Realms in
>             a universe of wonder, beauty, and
>             terror that they barely
>             comprehended. But for all their thirst for
>             knowledge, they let our lessons
>             fall into myth and dreams.

When Thor wants to go to Jötunheim after the ice giants try to steal the tesseract, Fandral says:

> This isn't like a journey to Earth,
>             where you summon a little lightning
>             and thunder and the mortals worship
>             you as a god. This is Jotunheim.

And in Earth, when Jane and Darcy are starting to think that he is actually the Thunder God, Darcy says:

> A primitive culture like the
>             Vikings might have worshipped them
>             as deities.

But in Infinity War Thor says he is 1500 years old. That means he was born in the year 500 after Christ.

So, is this possible? when did the norse people start worshiping Thor?

*Note: I took the quotes from the original Thor movie script* [here](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Thor.html)

Comment: I've removed the `infinity-war` tag, as the question only mentions the film and isn't really about it.

Comment: Real Thor is possibly as old as 2nd Century AD. Certainly existed as a deity from 700AD onwards.

Comment: Thor, like so many other pre-Christian deities in the Indo-European areas, harks back to a pantheon that far predates written records. He is obviously linked to Taranis, Perkūnas, Indra, and several other thunder gods in different panthea, but when exactly he developed into a specifically Thor-like incarnation—or indeed when his name became Thor (definitely no earlier than Common Germanic) is something we just don’t know. The former was definitely before 500 AD, and probably also the latter, but there is no direct evidence.

Comment: maybe asgard years are longer than ours?

Comment: This looks entirely like a question for [mythology.SE](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is belongs on https://mythology.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Just to be clear, all the quotes from the MCU are merely background.   The question is **When did the norse people start worshiping Thor?**

Comment: And just in case anyone thinks this wouldn't be a good fit for that site, look at [this question](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/477/is-mjolnir-actually-capable-of-flying-back-into-thors-hand-like-a-boomerang-aft)

Comment: Beginning of The Dark World implies that Norse mythology in the MCU only began c. 900 CE. So this is self-consistent, at least. Totally not surprised you either missed or didn't remember that movie. :)

Answer (score 5):

Written records of Thor go back [more than 1,900 years](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thor#Roman_era), so you’re correct to observe that an age of 1,500 years cannot be reconciled with the historical record.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked. It appears to be more of a comment.

Comment: Time dilation.  All that Bifrost travel adds up. (joke)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/126369)

Comment: Q: When did people start following Thor? A: Written records go back more than 1,900 years. What am I missing about that, @HelbentIV ? If it were a history or mythology site perhaps more discussion of prehistoric times would ensue, but the goal was to see if real myth timelines can be reconciled with Marvel timelines - and Mike provided a datapoint sufficient to answer that.